# Linear optimization of a battery storage

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

Im currently trying to optimize a battery storage with pyomo.
I thought everything was working but for some reason the storage is always getting discharged at the start. This should be impossible because the storage is empty at the beginning...

```
def discharge_capacity_rule(model, t):
    return model.discharge[t] <= in_out_leistung
model.discharge_capacity_rule = Constraint(model.t, rule = discharge_capacity_rule)
def charge_capacity_rule(model, t):
    return model.charge[t] <= in_out_leistung
model.charge_capacity_rule = Constraint(model.t, rule = charge_capacity_rule)

def max_capacity_rule(model, t):
    return model.soe[t] <= battery_capacity
model.max_capacity_rule = Constraint(model.t, rule = max_capacity_rule)

def soe_start_rule(model, t):
    return model.soe[0] == soe_start 
model.soe_start_rule = Constraint(rule = soe_start_rule)
def soe_end_rule(model, t):
    return model.soe[n] == model.soe[0]
model.soe_end_rule = Constraint(rule = soe_end_rule)

def soe_rule(model, t):
    if t == 0:
        return model.soe[t] == soe_start
    else:
        return model.soe[t] == model.soe[t-1] + (model.charge[t] * in_out_efficiency) - (model.discharge[t] / in_out_efficiency)
model.soe_rule = Constraint(model.t, rule = soe_rule)
```

[image: This is what the output looks like]

Comment: A quick fix would probably be to just say if t = 0 the storage cant be discharged. Not sure if this the best way though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue in the BESS optimization. You're constraining `model.discharge[t]` just for power (i.e., any discharge can't surpass the nominal power output of BESS), but there is not explicit constraint to discharging beyond available energy. The `model.soe` computation is a common way to avoid discharging beyond the  available stored energy, but during the initial time-step, your just avoiding the computation of state-of-charge for BESS and setting to initial value with `return model.soe[t] == soe_start`, therefore, discharging is not constrained to `model.soe_rule` in this time-step, since the following constraint applies for all time-step but initial one.

```
model.soe[t] == model.soe[t-1] + (model.charge[t] * in_out_efficiency) - (model.discharge[t] / in_out_efficiency)
```

You can try some approaches:

1. **Constraint discharge to available stored energy:**

   You can constraint `model.discharge[t]` to be less or equal than available stored energy any time.step. This is equivalent to the SOE computation, since `model.soe` cannot be less than zero, but that wouls also apply during the initial time-step. The constraint would be something like this:

   ```
    def discharge_leq_soe(model, t):
        model.discharge[t] <= model.soe[t]
    model.discharge_leq_soe = pyo.Constraint(model.t)
   ```
2. **Fix the initial charge:**

   As you comment, you can just say in the initial time-step, discharge in disallowed, that would set `model.discharge` to zero during initial time-step:

   ```
    model.initial_discharge_fixed = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.discharge[model.t.first()]==0)
   ```
3. **Not fixed initial soe:**

   You can also not fix the initial state-of-charge, but compute it. In this escenario, `model.charge` and `model.discharge` are unfixed and `model.soe[0]` is computed from the results. This can give you some sort of insights about required initial SOE to improve de BESS dispatch. In this approach you just need to change your `soe_rule` to:

   ```
    def soe_rule(model, t):
        if t == 0:
            return model.soe[t] == (model.charge[t] * in_out_efficiency) - (model.discharge[t] / in_out_efficiency)
        else:
            return model.soe[t] == model.soe[t-1] + (model.charge[t] * in_out_efficiency) - (model.discharge[t] / in_out_efficiency)
    model.soe_rule = Constraint(model.t, rule = soe_rule
   ```